# cgi with lighttpd on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cgi, lighttpd

Suppose I have an executable file with .o or .a extension. How can I run it on lightTPD? Should I allow cgi or just fast-cgi will be enough?

I am using ubuntu 9.04 and if this make any difference executable file supporting V8-engine.

the problem is I dont see any modcgi in my /etc/lighttpdlighttpd.conf, could just be wrong installed lighttpd or I am looking in the wrong way?

Comment: Does the executable file receive the parameters via environment variables? From standard input?

Comment: Executable file recieves data from the server like this http://localhost/?a=4&b=5 send this data to JS file which parse ans send it back to executable file. Well this actually all. So what configuration should i put into my lighttpd.conf to do it in Ubuntu, I already did it on windows, but on ubuntu I cant handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run `.o` or `.a` files via CGI (nor can you run them normally), because they're not linked yet. But, if you have a fully compiled and linked ELF binary, you could name it with the `.cgi` extension, and set `cgi.assign` to `".cgi" => ""`.